# Reuse same sql clause in script

Tags: sql, shell, unix

The case is that I have an SQL clause inside a unix script like:

```
sqlplus -s user/pass << END_SQL1 >> outfile.txt
set echo off feedback off heading off tab off;
select ..... 
from ....
where ...
and ...
and ... ;
END_SQL
```

If the `outfile.txt` is not empty, which means that I get a result from the above SQL, then I am running an update SQL that should change something at some DB elements.

Then I need to reuse the same SQL above to check if the DB elements that I wanted have changed indeed.  So, is that possible to reuse this same SQL, but WITHOUT including this same SQL code again later at the script, instead to run it again and, moreover, even put the result at another output file, e.g. `outfile2.txt` ?

Comment: You could wrap it in a shell function, say, `runquery`, and remove the `>> outfile.txt` part. Then you can use it like `runquery > outfile.txt` and later `runquery > outfile2.txt`. Notice that the `END_SQL` at the end of your here-doc is missing the `1` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RETURNING ... INTO  ...` clause inside the script

```
   UPDATE myTable
      SET col1 = <something1>
    WHERE col2 = <something2>
RETURNING col3, col1 INTO v_col3, v_col1;
```

to return the results into the variables `v_col3` and `v_col1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your hairy `SELECT` query in a file, say `select.sql`. Then whenever you need to run the SQL, you could just do :

```
sqlplus -s user/pass @select.sql >> outfile.txt
```

You can adapt the output file as you wish :

```
sqlplus -s user/pass @select.sql >> outfile2.txt
```

NB : you said

> If the outfile.txt is not empty, which means that I get a result from the above SQL

You probably want to use `>` when writing to `outfile.txt` : `>>` *appends* to the file, while `>` replaces it.